# Did I find Super Hidden files in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I seem to have found hidden files on Win 7 that have no address location nor can they be opened - they are not even clickable. I used Explorer++ to do a search for the string AT&T to test the search feature.

The search found the file I was looking for but as it continued searching it found what looks to be hidden Chinese files. I have no reason to have any Chinese files on my system, much less hidden Chinese files that cannot open or even be clicked on with no address location.

Here is a screenshot

[image]

What are these? If they are really files, I want to open and examine them. I'll need someone to tell me how to do that.

If they are not real files, what are they and why do they show up? I have tried other search tools and none shows these except Explorer++ so I assume it has something to do with their search algorithm.

Comment: I suspect that's nonsense caused by a bug in your search program.

Comment: That looks like a parser error caused by a bug in your code, detecting a code page and translating it incorrectly.